# What will happen if a young labrador is not given proper exercise?

Tags: dogs, health, maintenance, exercise

I am a college student in India. I own a four month old labrador dog. I just want to know about the importance of exercise for that breed. Can anyone help me?

Comment: The title asks about exercise (physical activity) but then you mention training (learning). Can you clarify what you are asking for? Use the edit function to write your concern in more detail and then a moderator will repoen the question.

Comment: Welcome to Pets SE. Your question, as currently written, is too broad. Please add sufficient detail to make the question answerable in a (potentially) canonical way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Training or exercice? What do you mean? In any case it is not really breed specific: any dog needs both mental and physical exercice. Mental exercice can be achieved by training games, food puzzles, etc. Physical exercice is equally important and for a large dog the more the better. I think 2 times 30 minutes walk is the absolute minimum.